# Get bean values in another bean in prime faces

Tags: java, primefaces

I want to access values from one bean to another bean in primefaces. I defined scope @SessionScoped.

But still when accessing value in another bean, I get `null`.

`FirstBean.java`

```
public void setDistrict(String district) {
    System.out.println("district set District Method "+district);
    this.district = district;
}  
public String getDistrict() {
    System.out.println("district get District Method" +district);
    return district;
}
```

When trying to access in `SecondBean.java`,it is returning `null`.

Comment: Are both beans JSF managed beans?? How are you trying to access the value of `FirstBean` on `SecondBean`? Please, show me some more code, so i can analyse it better.

Comment: yes ,both are beans JSF . Accessing Something like this : firstBean.getDistrict(); (firstBean is Object of FirstBean.java)

Comment: Ok, see my answer below, it shows you how to do it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you want to access `FirstBean.java` inside `SecondBean.java`, you can do it like this:

```
    ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
    FirstBean firstBean = (FirstBean) elContext.getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "firstBean");
```

Answer (score 3):

There is many ways to do that :

- Using **@ManagedProperty** :

Example :

FirstBean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "firstBean")
@SessionScoped
public class FirstBean implements Serializable {

//some Code here
```

SecondBean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "secondBean")
@SessionScoped
public class FirstBean implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value="#{firstBean}")
FirstBean firstBeanObject;
```

- Using **@Inject**

Example:

FirstBean

```
javax.inject.Named //for bean declaration
javax.inject.Inject //for injection

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class FirstBean implements Serializable{
// your code here
```

SecondBean

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SecondBean{

@Inject
FirstBean firstBean ;
//code here
```

- Or get your current Object from **FacesContext** if using SessionScoped